Am I allowed to pay rent or transfer to stock broker from my business sole proprietor account?
I am a registered sole proprietor working as a freelancer software engineer in Germany (although an expat).
I don't use business account for small expenses but I use it for:

Rent payment (I also work from home).

Transferring money to my stock broker account and vice-versa.


I transfer it through business account because it's more simpler than Business -> Personal -> Stock broker.
It's also more safer because I keep <2000 EUR in personal account and remaining under business account (where I have disabled debit card).
Question:

Am I allowed to do so?

What if I accidentally make a personal transaction with business account again in the future. What should I do to cover the damage?



This needs an answer from someone in Germany who knows the laws and accounting, not from people on the Internet. Talk to your accountant.

David R seems wholly correct and while you're here, I don't see how this relates to Freelancing as opposed to any other working- or life-style?
Why not asked an accountant?
Either way, who would doubt that some part, but not all of your rent payment was acceptable? Depending on your jurisdiction that might be based on floor area.
Transferring money to or from your stock broker account should always be irrelevant, in itself.
The difference between what you send and take back should be interesting to your tax inspector.
Again, why not asked an accountant?
